# Wordpress Menu vanishes when leaving parent item

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

I am using the default Wordpress Menu system.
I am using a custom theme, based on twenty ten.

I have everything styled and layed out the way i want it, but when i move the cursor form the parent item to the 1st drop item, the menu vanishes.

If the cursor is moved quickly enough directly to the 2nd (or lower) item, the menu does not vanish, and you can move the cursor back up to the 1st item without an issue.

The site is americanindustrialinc.com/wp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing the submenu on main menu item hover. However, since there is a small gap between the main menu item and the submenu, the user's mouse leaves out of the main menu item :hover and the submenu disappears. This can be fixed by the following:

```
#access ul ul {
   padding-top: 10px;
   top: 22px;
   // I'm showing only the styles that need to be added/changed
}
```

This way, there's an invisible padding covering the gap from the main menu item to the submenu, so the user's cursor stays in the :hover state and you get the intended behaviour.

Comment: So when you just put 'top: 22px' - thats margin, not padding?

Comment: top: 22px is just an offset from the default position, so that 22px is not part of the element. Margin is basically the same; only padding is counted as part of the element, so you stay in :hover.